# Is every geodesic space with non-positively curved metric triangulable?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Let $(X, d)$ be a geodesic space which is also a closed manifold. Suppose $d$ is a local $CAT(0)$ metric. Here is the question:

Is it true that $X$ admits a triangulation? (No requiring the triangulation to be PL).

An example of Davis and Januszkiewicz showed that there is a non-triangulable aspherical 4-manifold. Let $P^3$ be the Poincare Homology Sphere. They firstly constructed an aspherical 4 dimensional homology manifold via Gromov's hyperbolization, then replace the neighborhood around non-manifold point (the cone over $P^3$) by Freedman's 4-dimensional contractible manifold $W$ with the boundary $P^3$. It is the second step that the $CAT(0)$ condition is lost and I don't know anything about possible geometric properties of the mysterious $W$.

Comment: What does a "**closed** geodesic space" mean? Do you mean a **compact** geodesic space?

Comment: I mean it is a closed manifold, i.e. compact without boundary.

Comment: I see. Then, most likely, this is unknown.

Comment: It seems the answer follows from [Aspherical manifolds that cannot be triangulated, M. Davis, J. Fowler, and J-F. Lafont, Algebr. Geom. Topol. (2014)],  https://people.math.osu.edu/lafont.1/no_triangulation.pdf. Namely, on p.7 in the subsection "Word hyperbolicity" they build an example by gluing two locally CAT(-1) spaces along locally convex subspaces, and the result is a closed non-triangulable manifold of any dimension $\ge 6$. By gluing theorem this closed manifold is locally CAT(-1). What bothers me is that the authors only argue (in a different way) that $\pi_1$ is word hyperbolic.

Comment: I take back my comment. I communicated with Lafont, and they definitely don't prove what I claimed.